# Is it safe to set SPI_CLOCK clock speed of 16 MHz on Arduino Uno?

Tags: avr, arduino-uno, avrdude

I have an Arduino Uno R3 (actually, distributed from Elegoo but has the same exact components) and I thought about burning the ATMega 8 chip on it with a bootloader, using the "Arduino as ISP" feature on the Arduino IDE.

I looked at the specs for the ATMega 8 chip, and I would like to just ask - everywhere I've looked online, it says the default CPU clock speed is 16MHz, which makes sense because of the crystal clock onboard running at 16MHz. However, I'm not sure the code I have already written is safe:

```c
#define SPI_CLOCK   (16000000/6) // Internal clock speed 16 MHz for Arduino UNO.
```

I think that this code will be fine considering the specs. The example told me to set `SPI_CLOCK` to a value of `1000000/6`, which slow enough for an ATtiny85 (@ 1 MHz), but since I want to use the full functionality of the crystal I have onboard and want a faster clock speed, is it safe to set `SPI_CLOCK` directly to `16000000/6`?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, I am only planning on using the bootloader code for burning ATmega 8 chips.

Comment: I cannot understand what stops you from programming the flash on 1000000/6 baud rate? Surely 16MHz CPU will accept it.

Comment: @AterLux Okay, but will setting the baud rate at that value affect the execution speed of sketches that I upload to the chip? Like with time-sensitive functions like delay() or tone()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about exactly. Setting SPI clock speed on the programmer only affects how fast you can flash the device. It does not change how the flashed code works

Comment: All right, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, AterLux answered my question:

> Setting SPI clock speed on the programmer only affects how fast you can flash the device. It does not change how the flashed code works – AterLux